# Is there any tri-angle ?

Tags: geometry, triangles, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I want to find those tri-angle whose area is 100 square cm and having following features :

- Any height drawn from any top point of the tri-angle is not more than 1 cm ?

### My trying :

I know that the area of tri-angle is $ \frac{1}{2}*base*height$ So if the height is 1 cm then all the base should be 200 cm .

THen how should I go ahead ?

Comment: So why don't you just take a triangle with base 200 cm and height 1 cm?

Comment: What is a *top point* of a triangle and and an *height drawn from a top point*? The (usual) heights of a triangle fix the area of the triangle by Heron's formula.

Answer (score 1):

Take any triangle $\triangle ABC$ of area $100 \,\text{cm}^2$ with $B,C$ on a fixed line $\mathbf{L}\,$. Flatten the triangle by pushing vertex $A$ down towards $\mathbf{L}$ while sliding $B,C$ outwards along the line as to keep the area constant. In the limit, the distances from any point inside the triangle to either of the three sides tend to $0\,$, so all heights will eventually become $\le 1 \,\text{cm}$ for $\,A\,$ sufficiently close to $\,\mathbf{L}\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]   For a concrete example of such a triangle, consider a triangle $\triangle ABC$ isosceles at $A$ with base $400 \,\text{cm}$ and height $\frac{1}{2} \,\text{cm}\,$, so that thea area is $\,\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot 400 = 100 \,\text{cm}^2\,$. Then the equal sides will be $\sqrt{200^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2} \,\text{cm}\,$ each, and the corresponding heights are $\,\frac{2 \,\cdot\, 100}{\sqrt{200^2+\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}} \lt 1 \, \text{cm}\,$.

Comment: Can I determine any features of that tri-angles ?

Comment: @StandardEquation I added an example of such a triangle in the answer.